# AdapterView (TwoWayView) margin of item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview, android-adapterview

I'm using the `TwoWayView` library : https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view to try and implement a horizontal `ListView` of sorts to overhaul what I had before.  (`HorizontalScrollView` with a horizontally oriented `LinearLayout` that I add views to)

I want to have a `margin` before the first item, so there's a blank space at the left when the `View` is first created. But when scrolled, the blank space would be scrolled and disappear as well. When using a normal `ListView` it is essentially a `HeaderView` that I want.

When I implemented the scroll using `HorizontalScrollView`, I simply programmatically checked the first item and added the margin, which worked since its parent was `LinearLayout` and accepts margins. But I cannot do this in the `getView()` of the adapter used for this `AdapterView` since its `LayoutParams` do not inherit `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`

I've also tried setting `clipToPadding="false"`, but the views gets recycled too early, which is unacceptable since the padding I need is noticeably big.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior without moving all the `HeaderView` code from `ListView` into the `TwoWayView` library?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

on getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){}

```
{
            if (convertView == null)
            { ... }
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            /// To set your margin, you just need to test the position :)
            params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

            viewHolder.LinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
```

Hope this would help you.